# Find if a triangle lies within a specified region inside an image

Tags: python, math, graphics, geometry, cross-product

I want to understand the logic behind this code. This piece of code is in python and it tells if a triangle lies inside a specific region. "Vertices" contain the three vertices of the triangle and "p" contains all points in the specific region?

```py
def func(vertices, p):
    a, b, c = vertices
    cross1 = np.cross(b - a, p - a) <= 0
    cross2 = np.cross(c - b, p - b) <= 0
    cross3 = np.cross(a - c, p - c) <= 0
    return ~(cross1 ^ cross2) & ~(cross2 ^ cross3)
```

I am unable to understand the logic. Please help. Thanks

Comment: the mixture of boolean and bitwise expressions is convoluted and results in useless garbage (negative integers, -1 or -2 depending on operands). don't mix those things. stick with boolean operations. besides that, it's consoluted (I think I said that already), so it's also a terrible idea in general.  `cross1 == cross2 == cross3` is valid python and actually correct and readable

Comment: This function says whether point p lies inside triangle. Agree with Christoph about weird last line.

Comment: Thank you @ChristophRackwitz. This is helpful. Can you please explain what do you mean when you say the "expression is convoluted". I know about convolution operation  in general but what does it mean here?

Comment: not "convolved" but "convoluted" meaning complicated, twisted, baroque, byzantine, opaque, impenetrable... `~(cross1 ^ cross2)`, if not for the mixing of boolean and bitwise operations, would be `not (cross1 xor cross2)` (pseudocode), which equivalent to `cross1 == cross2`. the entire expression then reads as `(cross1 == cross2) and (cross2 == cross3)`